# Laravel api authenication not working

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am attempting to use authentication for application through api, but when I set the guard in middleware it does not work and returns 403 exception.

I have this route guard in controller constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Anytime I use `Auth::user()` the 403 is returned. Is something being missed?

Comment: You can get user from `$request->user()` in the controller action

Answer (score 0):

For using `Auth::user()` make sure your routes are protected by `api` `midlleware()`

For using a user u can specify

```
Auth::gaurd('api')->user();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not working and the gaurd spelling is guard